# Format doesnt change automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change format from Date to Number and It doesnt changes. I have to click two times on every cell to change it.

I found a solution that text to column works here. Unfortunatelly the recorded code doesn't work.

```
     Worksheets("Data for LN").Range("i2:i" & datarange).Select
     Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
     Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("I2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
          TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
          Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
          :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Any ideas how to change it?

Comment: Look at the [`Range.TextToColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) documentation, specifically the `FieldInfo` parameter. `Array(1, 1)` is not what you want.

Comment: First thing to do is to remove that `.Select` call, declare `Worksheet` and `Range` local variables, respectively assign them to `Worksheets("Data for LN")` and `theSheet.Range("i2:i" & datarange)`, and then work with `theRange` and `theSheet.Range(...)` instead of `Selection` and implicit `ActiveSheet`

Comment: I'm afraid you'd need to re-write your code to loop through each cell in a range and modify its data type separately. VBA has some serious issues recording `TextToColumns` functionality and it is even more difficult to write it from scratch. See Rory's solution [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/127225-text-to-columns-dmy-format-not-working/) for some alternatives.